# Unable to login after power outage

Tags: login, gdm, password

I have accidentally cut power to the computer and now I can't login with my main user. In GDM I enter the password correctly but it always says "wrong password".

Logging in with another user works. I changed the password for the main user, but it doesn't recognize the new password either.

How can I fix that?

Edit:
The file system check yielded no damage message. However, on rebooting the installed OS, I noticed the keyboard layout was set to EN-US which I don't use. But I swear before that it was set to the layout I normally use before the file system check. So everythings back to normal, I can log in. Thanks for everýbodys input.

Comment: Do a disk check from a live cd if you can, and then try again. If that does not work I will try to provide further instruction (unless someone else has a more immediate answer).

Comment: Does it have to be from a live disk? I can login with the other user just fine and when logged in like that can even become my main user.

Comment: Try to change to your main user and then change the password, does that work?

Comment: BTW: were you using an encrypted home directory?

Comment: That is what I meant with the second paragraph. The home directory is not encrypted.

Comment: I can log in. Details in my edit. Thanks for everýbodys input.

Comment: @moter post that as your answer and mark it solved please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file system check using a live cd yielded no damage message. However, on rebooting the installed OS, I noticed the keyboard layout was set to EN-US which I don't use. But I swear, before the file system check it was set to the layout I normally use. So everything is back to normal, I can log in. Thanks for everýbodys input.